# Rails method to monitor status of a variable for a set period of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

Trying to setup a method that will give customers a discount if a certain sales volume is met in a set period of time. 
I have 6 variables

1- units_sold - total number of items sold

2- sales_volume - sales volume required to get a certain benefit

3- sales_time - the amount of time available to meet the required sales volume

4- price - regular price of item

5- discount - discount granted if sales_volume met within sales_time

6- final_price - price customer pays

and i tried to create the method like this...

```
def speed_discount ( unit_sales, product)
  while product.sales_time != 0
   if unit_sales(product)==product.volume
    final_price = price+discount
  else final_price = price
  end
 end
end
```

The method should monitor sales_time and units_sold and if the required sales_volume is met before sales_time expires it updates the price to reflect the additional discount. i've tried the following but i think something is wrong with the While stmt and i dont know how to  have sales_time start counting down.

Comment: see question at for answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036048/comparing-datetime-variables-in-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered elsewhere on the site. see the link below

see question at for answer
[Comparing datetime variables in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036048/comparing-datetime-variables-in-rails)